# How to make an IoT Framework on Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, iot, azure-iot-hub, aws-iot, google-smart-home

I have started looking into IoT and interested to know how to make IoT framework especially for a manufacturing process on cloud computing environment. I am not sure how to make a IoT framework , suppose i have four or five IoT sensors are being used in a manfucturing environment than how can i use them to create a framework on cloud such google or Azure etc.
Can anybody comment on it . much appreciated 
Nhqazi

Comment: Maybe have a read at the following:

https://cloud.google.com/iot-core/
https://aws.amazon.com/iot/
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/

These may answer or, if not, may help you to focus the questions.

Comment: You'll want to read up on what the different cloud providers offer for IoT solutions, then ask more specific questions here. This questions is far too broad for anyone to answer here on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there should be some explanation - let me prepare it for you.
There are different cloud providers which offers services dedicated for IoT solutions, for instance:

1. Microsoft Azure cloud offers: [Azure IoT Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-hub/)
2. Amazon offers: [AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/what-is-aws-iot.html)
3. Google offers: [Google Cloud IoT](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/iot/)

Now each of theese service offers some tools to integrate them with IoT devices. This is I think what you are talking about. For instance Microsoft provides [Azure IoT Hub SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks) so you can use it to send data from your device to the cloud and from the cloud to the device.

Now if you have devices and sensors you can intgrate them with cloud services mentioned above. Here you can see how I integrated Raspberry PI2 device and motion sensor with Azure IoT Hub from Microsoft:

https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/cloudyofthings/article1/index